# Programatically init angular controller from browser console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to programatically initialize a controller from the browser javascript console. How can I do this?

I tried

```
>> document.body.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'MainCtrl')
```

But this does not init anything.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying something like this. It does not work because the angular already finished its compilation, anything added after that will not be recognized. You may need to compile it manually, but that depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: because I don't have direrct access to the javascript file being loaded. I am debugging something